# Using Expander in Grid, having expanded area use all space

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, expander

I have an `Expander` in a `Grid`. 
Is there an easy way to let the expander use the avaible space (perhaps a full row in the grid)?

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfExpanderSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="400">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"  />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"  />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"  />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"  />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"  />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="11111" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="22222" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="33333" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="44444" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="55555" />
        <Expander Grid.Column="5" Header="Expand me" ExpandDirection="Down" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" >
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Expanded text which is eventually very long and shall take all space available" />
        </Expander>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now I want the expanded area to "occupy" a full row in the grid. 
It seems to only take the remaining space that is in that one GridCell.
Can the expanded content be displayed anywhere else?

Do I have to make an extra Button to achieve what I want? (setting some visible attribute for the expanded area or something like that)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the easiest way of doing what you're asking for is not to use `Expander`. You can just put `Grid` on top with some `ToggleButton` to the right and control below which `Visibility` will depend on `ToggleButton.IsChecked`

```
<StackPanel>
   <StackPanel.Resources>
       <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
   </StackPanel.Resources>
   <Grid>
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition/>
           <ColumnDefinition/>
           <ColumnDefinition/>
           <ColumnDefinition/>
           <ColumnDefinition/>
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <TextBox Text="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
       <TextBox Text="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
       <TextBox Text="2" Grid.Column="2"/>
       <TextBox Text="3" Grid.Column="3"/>
       <ToggleButton Content="V" Grid.Column="4" x:Name="btnExpander"/>
   </Grid>
   <Grid Visibility="{Binding ElementName=btnExpander, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
       <TextBlock Text="LongText"/>
   </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

of course `ToggleButton` needs some decent `Template` but it's just to give you an example

Comment: Probably I have to do something like that. I have a decent behavior on the Expander that makes it slide in, hoped that I can use it.

Comment: You can put some `StoryBoard` on that as well and it will slide in but I don't think you can do that just with `Expander`

Comment: Will go the ToggleButton way. Thank you very much!